# How to Add cursor files in resources of control Library project

Tags: c#, .net

I am creating a Control Library project.
I have some Cursor files which i want to add on resources.

Because on Resources.resx--->Add resources is only for String, Icon (*.ico), Text file(*.txt),
Image (Png,bmp,jpeg,gif, tiff) files.

So where i can add *.cur files.
How can i do it?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7097044/how-to-create-an-embedded-resource-cursor-in-c-sharp-winforms

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is also a category **Other**. There you can add anything you like.

Also you can click on the little down arrow next to *Add Resource* and click on *Add Existing File ...*. It will put it automatically in the correct category.

#### Update

Ok. So the problem is not adding the file to the resources. Instead loading it from there makes the problem, cause the [Cursor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.cursor.aspx) only supports a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.io.stream.aspx), but not a byte[].

In that case you should put it into a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) and give this to the Cursor constructor.

```
Cursor myCursor;
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.MyCursorFile))
{
    myCursor = new Cursor(memoryStream);
}
```

Comment: see my comment given to David Morton.
I have problem with converting byte [] of cursor (generated by resouces file) into Cursor object.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you click "Add Resources..."  There is an option for "Add Existing File..."  Choose it and select your file.

Comment: i tried this earlier but i have problem with the code generated by Resource file.

See the code when you add any image file.(Bmp, Png, ico,Gif,Tiff)
Resource file generate following code

  internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap QuestionIcon {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("YourIconName", resourceCulture);
                return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
            }
        }

It return Bitmap which you can easily use in your project like.

public Bitmap questImage = Test.Properties.Resources.QuestionIcon ;

Comment: But When you add cur file it return a byte [] like below.

 internal static byte[] mdColor {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("mdColor", resourceCulture);
                return ((byte[])(obj));
            }
        }

I tried to convert it into Cursor but not successful.See my code
public byte[] magImage = CursorTest.Resource1.mdRectMag;
unsafe { fixed (byte* ptr = magImage){ IntPtr myPtr = new IntPtr((void*)ptr);Cursor myCur = new Cursor(myPtr);                     return myCur;
}
return null;
}

Answer (score 0):

thanks Friends

I have done it.
I used following code for conversion:

```
Cursor My = new Cursor(new System.IO.MemoryStream(CursorTest.Resource1.MyCurFile));
```

Comment: Oh, seems that you already found the solution by yourself, but you should put the MemoryStream into a using statement like in my example or call `myMemoryStream.Close()`.